# firefox ignoring proxy settings and connecting directly

Tags: 12.04, networking, firefox, proxy

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and it's been a couple of months that I have this problem.

The problem is that firefox's proxy settings has no effect on it and despite what settings I set in `Edit->Preferences->Advanced-Network->Settigs`, it always connects directly to the Internet. Configuring by `FoxyProxy` extension does not work too.

Even setting System's settings (`System settings->Network->Network Proxy->Apply system wide`) has no effect.

Other browsers like Chrome work fine.

System Information:
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit
Firefox 26.0 (I had this problem in 25 too)

**SOLVED:** I don't know why, but once I run `sudo firefox` the problem went away!

Comment: Are the settings still there after you close and re-open the browser? Perhaps they are not being saved for some reason.

Comment: Yes they are there.